# Background on footer widget

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

:-) I have a wordpress site with a white footer widget that include Global site tag - Google Analytics. The code is this (see image). How can I change the color of the widget so that it appears black without losing indexing and SEO data? Now it appears in white.

I tried to enclose in an HTML code but it doesn't seem like a good idea

the code is this

"

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XYXYXYXYXY"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XYXYXYXYXY');
</script>
```

"

Answer (score 0):

```
#your-widget-id {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
   
}
```

You can replace `#your-widget-id` with your widget id or you can use the class.